# Diagonal principal guardada en arreglo unidimensional

Tags: java, array

Una consulta, la orden que tengo es esta y ya la resolvi excepto que no se como se hace para guardar la multiplicacion de la diagonal principal por el escalar en un nuevo arreglo unidimensional, porfavor ayuda gracias.
Definir y crear un arreglo bidimensional cuadrado de (m x m - m filas x m columnas), llenar el
arreglo con números aleatorios, multiplicar los elementos de la diagonal principal por un escalar
y almacenarlos en un arreglo unidimensional e imprimir los resultados.

```
public static void DiagEscalar (int limite, int escalar)
        {
            int [][] DiagoPrincipal;
            DiagoPrincipal = new int [limite][limite];
            
            int [] Resultado = null;
                   
            for (int i = 0; i < DiagoPrincipal.length; i++) 
            {
                 for (int j = 0; j < DiagoPrincipal[0].length; j++)
                 {
                    DiagoPrincipal[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*100); 
                 }
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < DiagoPrincipal.length; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < DiagoPrincipal[0].length; j++) 
                {
                    System.out.print(DiagoPrincipal[i][j]+ "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            
            System.out.println("Los elementos de la diagonal principal son: " );
            
            for(int i=0;i<DiagoPrincipal.length;i++)
            {
          for(int j=0;j<DiagoPrincipal[i].length;j++)
              {
            if(i==j)
                {
            int DiagonalPrincipal = DiagoPrincipal[i][j];
                    System.out.print(DiagonalPrincipal +"\t");
                    
                    DiagoPrincipal[i][j] *= escalar;
                    Resultado = new int [DiagoPrincipal[i][j]];
            }
                
              }
            } 
            System.out.println();
            
    }
```

Comment: Si tenes que guardar un array (como el que tenes) pero de una sola dimension (que seria igual a la cantidad de filas, digamos i)... porque no haces eso?

Comment: Podria ayudarme con el codigo de la idea que tiene porfavor? no le entiendo

Comment: Hola Melanie, podrías marcar como aceptada la respuesta más te haya servido, y si lo consideras dar tu voto positivo también, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al tener una matriz bidimensional de `[limite][limite]` los valores de la `diagonalPrincipal` serán del mismo tamaño de `[limite]`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ende podes declarar el array unidimensional de la siguiente manera.

```
int[]resultado=new int[limite];
```

y agregar los valores de la `diagonalPrincipal*escalar`

```
public static void diagEscalar (int limite, int escalar){

    int [][] diagoPrincipal = new int [limite][limite];
    int [] resultado = new int[limite];
                   
    for (int i = 0; i < diagoPrincipal.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < diagoPrincipal[0].length; j++){
          diagoPrincipal[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*100); 
         }
       }
            
    for (int i = 0; i < diagoPrincipal.length; i++){
       for (int j = 0; j < diagoPrincipal[0].length; j++) {
              System.out.print(diagoPrincipal[i][j]+ "\t");
          }
          System.out.println();
        }
            
    System.out.println("Los elementos de la diagonal principal son: " );
            
     for(int i=0;i<diagoPrincipal.length;i++){
          for(int j=0;j<diagoPrincipal[i].length;j++){
            if(i==j){
            int diagonalPrincipal = diagoPrincipal[i][j];
            System.out.print(diagonalPrincipal +"\t");
         //agregar los valores obtenidos al array unidimensional
            resultado[i]=diagonalPrincipal*escalar;          
                } 
            }            
    }

   System.out.println("\nElementos de la diagonalPrincipal * escalar");
   for(int i:resultado){
     System.out.print(i+"\t");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para recorrer la **diagonal principal** con un solo **ciclo for** resuelves, ya que tanto el índice de la fila como el índice de la columna son iguales:

```
int[] resultado = new int[limite];

for(int i = 0; i < diagoPrincipal.length; i++)
{
   resultado[i] = escalar * diagoPrincipal[i, i];
}
```

Declaras un arreglo unidimensional de la misma longitud que la matriz original, posteriormente haces un **ciclo for** y vas guardando la multiplicación del escalar por la diagonal de la matriz.